# In Java how do I find out what languages I have available my Resource Bundle

Tags: java, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have some resource bundles packaged in my main jar

```
widget_en.properties
widget_de.properties
```

I retrieve a resource bundle based on my default locale as folows

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("widget", Locale.getDefault());
```

But I want to present the user with a list of available languages supported so that can select a language that may be different to their computers default

But I can't find a method in ResourceBundle that would list available locales, I don't want to hardcode a list as I may forget to update it when another resource bundle is added.

**EDIT**

As I only resource bundles for different language (I dont have country refinements) so I have got generated a list by iterating through all the known language codes and check for each one as a resource.

```
String[]langs = Locale.getISOLanguages();
for(String lang:langs)
{
      URL rb = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("widget_"+lang+".properties");
      if(rb!=null)
      {
            System.out.println("Found:"+rb.toString());
      }
}
```

Comment: this is a great question and a great opportunity for Java to provide a utility method to return application specific available resources.  My research has turned up no useful solution other than iterating or searching files which seems a waste of resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is an API for this because new valid locale objects can be created on the fly:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("abcd");
```

without the need to register it somewhere. And then you can use a resource bundle 
`widget_abcd.properties` without restrictions:

```
ResourceBundle resource= ResourceBundle.getBundle("widget", new Locale("abcd"));
```

From the `java.util.Locale` API docs:

> Because a Locale object is just an identifier for a region, no
>   validity check is performed when you construct a Locale. If you want
>   to see whether particular resources are available for the Locale you
>   construct, you must query those resources.

To solve the problem you can still iterate over all files called "widget_" in the resource directory and discover the new added resource bundles.

Note that `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` **is not 100% sure** for the above reason: you might some day define a non standard locale. But if you'll add only a few standard locales you can use this static method to iterate over the system locales and get the corresponding bundles.

Comment: Okay I see wht you mean. I'm thinking about doing the iteration  but the files are within a jar not directly within a os folder, so how do I do that ?

Comment: The best idea that comes into my mind is to use the java Zip API and to look inside the jar for files named `widget_*.properties`

Comment: Problem is where the jar file is is relative to your working directory ectera (i/e on oSX this can be trickly to establish), so I tried using classloader but it doesnt support any kind of wildcard seaerch i.e ClassLoader.getSystemResources("widget_en.properties"); finds one file but ClassLoader.getSystemResources("widget_*"); returns nothing

Comment: If you'll add only a few standard locales you can use Locale.getAvailableLocales() to iterate over the system locales and get the corresponding bundles. But is not 100% sure.

Answer (score 7):

If you really package the resource files *inside* your JAR, then I would do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Set<ResourceBundle> resourceBundles = getResourceBundles(A.class.getName());
  if (resourceBundles.isEmpty())
    // ...
}

public static Set<ResourceBundle> getResourceBundles(String baseName) {
  Set<ResourceBundle> resourceBundles = new HashSet<>();

  for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    try {
      resourceBundles.add(ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName, locale));
    } catch (MissingResourceException ex) {
      // ...
    }
  }

  return Collections.unmodifiableSet(resourceBundles);
}
```

If you care about your JARs then you would at least get a set containing the default resource for a given `baseName`.

If you have only resources with names like `baseName_<country>` this method works perfectly, because only those `ResourceBundles` will be added to the set which are present in your JAR. It'll work even if you decide you need separate `baseName_en_US` and `baseName_en_UK` resources, which is not unheard of.

<sub>Shameless self-plug: I wrote a [`ResourceBundle.Control`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) which takes a [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) as its argument, you might be interested in it if you want to load UTF-8 encoded resources files. [It's available at GitHub.](https://github.com/kohanyirobert/java-util-resource-bundle-charset-control)</sub>

Comment: Yes I really do package them within my jar, in a previous project I did not, but not Im using maven to build it seemed to want to put it in the jar, is that wierd ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor I like it when static resources are truly static. I don't like adding checks to my code like `new File(file).exists()` even if I only want to read a damn property from that file, which is *there* 99.9% of the time. Anyways, I think you have to apply *some level of hack* to your code if you want to load properties from external files with the ResourceBundle class - although I'm not sure - so it doesn't really matter either way.  Bottom line: I think you're doing it just fine.

Comment: Oh I see you mean storing them outside of java file rather than storing them in properties file within/outside of jar. Storing the resource bundles as properties files allows me to use tools to easily edit and translate the properties to other languages.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I meant that if you have a JAR `application.jar` the resource property file should be inside this JAR (for localizable content at the least). Sorry if I was confusing.

Comment: Still don't understand your point, yes they are in the main jar thats what I said,or is application.jar a particular naming convention in application servers, if so not relevant for this desktop application

Comment: @PaulTaylor I was referring to the fact that you could have store your localizable properties elsewhere, like *beside* your JAR file. In this case, as I know, you couldn't have used the `ResourceBundle` class in the first place. Sorry again for being confusing, I was confused myself, because when I wrote my post I thought for a minute that you can use `ResourceBundle` to read stuff from arbitrary property files (although one could write a custom control for doing so).

Answer (score 3):

A solve it by listing files.

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static final ArrayList<String> LOCALES = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        try {
            File f = new File(JavaApplication1.class.getResource("/l10n").toURI());
            final String bundle = "widget_";// Bundle name prefix.
            for (String s : f.list(new FilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.startsWith(bundle);
                }
            })) {
                LOCALES.add(s.substring(bundle.length(), s.indexOf('.')));
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException x) {
            throw new RuntimeException(x);
        }
        LOCALES.trimToSize();
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: This is missing some code and doesn't compile as written.

Comment: Fixed, please check again.

Answer (score 2):

If you can make two basic assumptions:

1)  You have a default resource bundle with no locale, or at least one locale that you know is there.

2)  All your resources are in the same location (ie. the same path within a single jar file)

Then you can get the URL for a single resource:

```
URL url = SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("widget.properties");
```

once you have that, you should be able to parse the URL.

If you use commons-vfs, you should be able to convert the URL into  a FileObject:

```
FileSystemManager manager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject resource = manager.resolveFile(url.toExternalForm());
FileObject parent = resource.getParent();
FileObject children[] = parent.getChildren();
// figure out which ones are bundles, and parse the names into a list of locales.
```

This will save you the trouble of dealing with the complexities of jar: style url's and such,
since vfs will handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution,hope can help people.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.AndFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.PrefixFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.SuffixFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils; 
private static Locale[] getAvailableLocales(String name) { 
    String path = thisClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
    if (path.contains("%20")) {
        path = path.replaceFirst("%20", " ");
    }
    File file = new File(path);
    Locale[] array = FileUtils.listFiles(file, new AndFileFilter(new PrefixFileFilter(name), new SuffixFileFilter(".properties")),null)
            .stream()
            .map(File::getName)
            .map(v -> StringUtils.substringBetween(v, name + '_', ".properties"))
            .map(v->v.replaceFirst("_","-"))
            .map(Locale::forLanguageTag)
            .toArray(Locale[]::new);
    return array;
}
```